# Filtering a CTE in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to filter cte data by procedure parameters- in fact if @agentid is null gives me all data else filter data by @agentid . I tried many ways , I used case in cte and get erros , I used if in ( if @status after cte ) and I get errors to , I used if in cte and get errors

This procedure is for pagination and filter data and in works fine .

```
USE [HN_PRODUCTION]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[grid_data_pagination]  
    @status int  = null 
    , @offset int = 0 
    , @limit int = 2  
    , @agentid int = null 
    , @start_date date = null 
    , @end_date date = null                         
AS
BEGIN         
    IF  @status is  null  
    BEGIN       
            with cte as 
            (
                Select  FilePath  , ReceptionLocalTime , AgentID , FileDuration   , PhoneNumber , Indice   , Status  , ROW_NUMBER() over (  order by ID ) as RowNumber
                from dbo.V1_594                 
            )

    select FilePath as مسیر ,ReceptionLocalTime as زمان , FileDuration as مدت , PhoneNumber  as تلفن , Indice as اندیس , Status as وضعیت 
    from cte
    where cte.RowNumber > @limit * @offset and cte.RowNumber <= @limit * ( @offset + 1 )                                
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        with cte as 
        (
            Select  FilePath  , ReceptionLocalTime   , FileDuration   , PhoneNumber , Indice   , Status  , ROW_NUMBER() over (  order by ID ) as RowNumber
            from dbo.V1_594
            WHERE Status = @status 
        )

        select FilePath as مسیر ,ReceptionLocalTime as زمان , FileDuration as مدت , PhoneNumber  as تلفن , Indice as اندیس  
        from cte
        where cte.RowNumber > @limit * @offset and cte.RowNumber <= @limit * ( @offset + 1 ) ;
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be helpful to include the errors you get, but perhaps this will help.
If I understand the problem correctly, you want to filter out the values of the CTE?

You don't need the IF statement for status. You can do that all in the where clause

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[grid_data_pagination]  
    @status int  = null 
    , @offset int = 0 
    , @limit int = 2  
    , @agentid int = null 
    , @start_date date = null 
    , @end_date date = null                         
AS
BEGIN


    with cte as 
    (
        Select FilePath, ReceptionLocalTime, AgentID, FileDuration, PhoneNumber, Indice, Status, ROW_NUMBER() over (  order by ID ) as RowNumber
        from dbo.V1_594  
        WHERE (@agentid IS NULL OR AgentId = @agentid)
        AND (@status IS NULL OR Status = @status)
    )

    select FilePath as مسیر ,ReceptionLocalTime as زمان , FileDuration as مدت , PhoneNumber  as تلفن , Indice as اندیس  
    from cte
    where cte.RowNumber > @limit * @offset and cte.RowNumber <= @limit * ( @offset + 1 ) ;
END
```

Hope that helps